# Will this execute without any race condition

Tags: c++, c, atomic

Suppose I have this code executed by two different threads T1 and T2 that might be running on two different cores. Note that this code gets executed repeatedly and `x` is initially 0, so that T1 passes the while loop first time.

Will it work deterministically and have no race conditions. Do I need locks or atomic variables here?

Also note that only T1 modifies the reference value and it doesn't touch it until T2 has set x to 0 again. Also, all variables used are integers.

I am interested to know a scenario where it can go wrong. I will be grateful if someone provides me an example scenario.

### EDIT

Assume the platform is x86.

### T1

```
r = modify_and_get_reference_value();
while ( x != 0 )
 ;
x = r;
```

### T2

```
while( x != get_reference_value() )
 ;
x = 0;
```

Comment: What is `get_reference_value()`?

Comment: + what types are `r` and `x`?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again ? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235363/do-i-need-an-atomic-integer-variable-here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235363/do-i-need-an-atomic-integer-variable-here)

Comment: My previous question wasn't understood and I received negative responces. This time I made it more clear.

Comment: You believe the previous question(s) were not understood. Have you considered the possibility that you didn't understand the answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rule of thumb: different threads execute on different planets, each using their own copy of main memory made at the point the child thread started, and updated only when absolutely necessary. They *never* communicate, and each one *never* sees the results of changes to memory made by the other, unless you use synchronization or atomic types.

That's not the worst-case for all code, so it's not the only scenario to consider, but I think it breaks your code if you don't use any locks or atomic variables - each thread would only look at its own version of `x`, they never allow the value to be synchronized between the two. Therefore the code would have a data race.

Comment: **Moderator Note** _Comments under this answer were removed because they degenerated into noise. Please keep comments professional, constructive and on topic._

Comment: **Author Note** Except for one, the comments removed were constructive and on-topic. They were non-professional only in the sense that I wasn't paid. Almost all of it was a discussion of possible implementation details that could cause the questioner's code to fail due to data races. The one exception was a comment by me concerning the questioner's motive in asking the question. I would have been happy had that been removed without also removing the substantive and relevant technical details that supplemented this answer. I am unhappy that useful info was removed and not edited into my answer.

Comment: @Tim I agree with Steve. You have erased useful information and made this answer worse. Please can you restore the deleted content.

Comment: @David Heffernan - No, unfortunately I can't. I'm sorry if I've mistakenly removed useful comments. Several long time users flagged to indicate that comments were getting a bit out of hand here and I agreed. I didn't want to leave a horribly broken conversation by removing odd parts of it.